# regex pattern - extract a string only if separated by a hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I've looked at other questions, but they didn't lead me to an answer.

I've got this code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("exp_(\\d{1}-\\d)-(\\d+)");
```

The string I want to be matched is: `exp_5-22-718`

I would like to extract `5-22` and `718`. I'm not too sure why it's not working What am I missing? Many thanks

Comment: Will there always be 2 hyphens?

Comment: You forgot the quantifier after 2nd `\\d`. Use `exp_(\\d-\\d+)-(\\d+)`

Comment: @RohitJain - That was exactly it! damn I feel stupid now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("exp_(\\d-\\d+)-(\\d+)");
```

In your original pattern you specified that second number should contain exactly one digit, so I put `\d+` to match as more digits as we can.
Also I removed `{1}` from the first number definition as it does not add value to regexp.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always prefixed with `exp_` I wouldn't use a regular expression.

I would:

- [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) `exp_`
- [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the resulting string on `-`

**Note:** This answer is based on the assumptions. I offer it as a more robust if you have multiple hyphens. However, if you need to validate the format of the digits then a regular expression may be better.

Comment: this would not work since op wants `5-22` and `718` **not** `5` `22` `718`

Comment: Thanks for the answer the string will only ever have two hyphens. All the strings will be structured as per the example above. This is why I want to use regex (plus I'll be using the regex to do a FileFilter.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ, understood. You can piece them back together. This answer was provided as an alternative to regular expressions. As noted it is based on *assumptions*. Thanks for the down vote though.

Comment: and even if you are splitting it only on the second hyphen you would be complicating things a lot when on the other hand you can use `regex` and access required data through `groups`

Answer (score 1):

In your regexp you missed required quantifier for second digit `\\d`. This quantifier is `+` or `{2}`.

```
    String yourString = "exp_5-22-718";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("exp_(\\d-\\d+)-(\\d+)").matcher(yourString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //prints 5-22
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); //prints 718
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string.split methods to do this. Check the following code.
I assume that your strings starts with "exp_".

```
    String str = "exp_5-22-718";
    if (str.contains("-")){
        String newStr = str.substring(4, str.length());
        String[] strings = newStr.split("-");

        for (String string : strings) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned i'm using regex because I Want to apply a filefilter. Thanks for the alternative method though!